# Show that $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is not uniformly continuous for $x \in (0,1), \frac{1}{x} \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity, uniform-continuity

I am meant to show that for $x \in (0,1)$,  $\frac{1}{x}$ is not uniformly continuous.

I am able to come up with a proof but the given hint tells me to investigate $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$, $y_n = \frac{1}{n+1}$ and I'm not sure how to use that to construct a proof.

Is it something to do with Cauchy sequences?

Comment: Hint: a uniformly continuous function takes Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences.

Comment: OK am I supposed to show that this function doesn't?

Comment: consider f(x_n) and f(y_n)

Comment: Yes. That's an easy way to show it is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: I'm still not sure what I get when considering $f(x_n)$ and $f(y_n)$

Comment: you could probably even use this sequence with the definition of uniform continuity. sequences are often used in limit problems because they're more tangible than points running along the real line.

Comment: @BradyTrainor how would I do that exactly?

Comment: @Mathlete, to my second comment? I'll reply below. To my first comment? f(x_n)=n is not Cauchy. Sorry, at that point I guess you can ignore y_n.

Comment: @BradyTrainor I think I get it actually, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it has to do with Cauchy sequences. A uniformly continuous function takes Cauchy sequences into Cauchy sequences.

Recalling the definition of uniformly continuous:

> For each $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that for each $x,y\in D$ $$|x-y|< \delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$$

It's negation would be that there exists one epsilon such that for each $\delta >0$ there exists two points $x,y$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ yet $|f(x)-f(y)|\geq \epsilon$. By taking $\delta=1,\frac 1 2,\frac 1 3,\dots$, we can write this as

> There exists an $\epsilon >0$ and two sequence of points $x_n,y_n$ such that $$|x_n-y_n|<\frac 1 n\; ;\;n=1,2,3,\dots$$ but $$|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|\geq \epsilon \; ;\; n=1,2,3,\dots$$

In your case, $\epsilon=1$; $$x_n=\frac 1n $$ and $$y_n=\frac 1{n+1}$$ do the job.

Comment: How would I construct a proof though?

Comment: So I'm just saying that $\frac{1}{n}$, $\frac{1}{n+1}$ are Cauchy sequences, which are mapped to $n, n+1$ respectively by the function, which are not Cauchy sequences and so the function is not uniformly continuous?

Comment: @Mathlete I added a longer explanation.

Comment: I think I understand, thanks @PeterTamaroff

Answer (score 0):

Or even simpler(?): A uniformly continuos function on a bounded domain is bounded.

Comment: Yes but I have to consider $x_n$ and $y_n$ in my proof.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose to the contrary, that f is uniformly continuous.

Fix $\epsilon$. By hypothesis, there is some $\delta$ such that, if

$$|y_n-x_n|<\delta,$$

then $|f(y_n)-f(x_n)|<\epsilon$. Can you fill in the details?